# Ruby Access Control - Specify with method or listed at ACL function?

Tags: ruby

I see there are two ways to specify access control in Ruby. One with access modifier specified with the method and the other as a list to the ACL function.

E.g. with the access modifier specified with the method

```
class MyClass
    public
        def method1
            #...
        end
    private
        def method2
            #...
        end

end
```

and another way where you specify the access as a list to the ACL function

```
class MyClass
        def method1
            #...
        end
        def method2
            #...
        end
        public :method1
        private :method2
end
```

Is there any reason to use one over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you use the first method you described. You would first have all public methods grouped together (without `public` specified, since it is the default at the beginning), followed by all protected methods grouped together, finally followed by all private methods grouped together. An example:

```
class C

  def first_public_method
    #...
  end

  def second_public_method
    #...
  end

  protected

    def protected_method_1
      #...
    end

    def protected_method_2
      #...
    end

  private

    def one_private_method
      #...
    end

    def another_private_method
      #...
    end

end
```

The second method you described in your question is rarely used, mostly for doing some tricks. It allows you to do the following things for example that are impossible with the first method:

- Dynamically build a list of methods that should have a certain visibility and then set that visibility by calling the appropriate method with the dynamic list, e.g. `public(*an_array_containing_names_of_all_methods_that_should_be_public)`
- Change the visibility of a method after a class has been defined

An example for the second point above:

```
class C

  #...

  private

    def a_private_method
      #...
    end

end

instance = C.new
instance.a_private_method # raises NoMethodError

C.send(:public, :a_private_method) # changes the visibility of the method dynamically to public
instance.a_private_method # executes the formerly private method without error
```

Answer (score 0):

If specify the modifier with the method, it's right there with the method definition, not hidden away somewhere. Conventionally you might groupall the private methods at the bottom of the file with one `private` modifier as these modifiers like `private`, `public`, `module_function` (others?) work as "everything below this line until you meet a contradictory one".

Alternately, you could use the method form but then I'd place them as near to the top as possible so it's obvious. Hang on, would that lead into a "this method isn't defined, so what the hell am I private-ing???" exception? In that case I'd group them at the bottom. The point being to not scatter them in the middle.